# Set Android environment variables to work with Maven

Tags: android, maven, environment-variables

I want to know how to set up correctly environment variables on a Mac. My OS is Mountain Lion and I'm getting the following output when trying to run "mvn clean install":

```
 org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: No Android SDK path could be found. You may configure it in the plugin configuration section in the pom file using <sdk><path>...</path></sdk> or <properties><android.sdk.path>...</android.sdk.path></properties> or on command-line using -Dandroid.sdk.path=... or by setting environment variable ANDROID_HOME
```

Comment: did you have pom.xml file in your project?

Comment: Yes, this project was created under a Windows machine and it compiles ok with maven

Comment: so change the Android SDK path according to your MAC in pom.xml

Comment: This is not the reason of my problem. My pom.xml doesn't contain information about the sdk path

Comment: then provide the android sdk path in that.